# Java Reflection Property String name ->Class Datatype

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to specify the String name of a property in a particular bean and return the class that the getter corresponds to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [java.beans.Introspector](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) class to obtain information about a given bean.  You can't query the [BeanInfo](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) for a **specific** property, but you can loop through them:

```
private Class<?> getPropertyType(Class<?> clazz, String property) {
    BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz);
    PropertyDescriptor[] propDescriptors = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
    for (PropertyDescriptor propDescriptor : propDescriptors) {
        // String name of a property
        if (property.equals(propDescriptor.getName())) {
           // Class the getter corresponds to.
           return propDescriptor.getPropertyType();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you know if BeanUtil can do this?

Comment: I guess so, but you probably ought to state that you're using Apache Commons before you ask the question!

Answer (score 0):

Found it...
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getPropertyType(Object bean, String name)